# Llibwebsockets built with cmake generates errors

Tags: cmake, openssl, libwebsockets

I want to use libwebsockets library bt while building it using cmake it gives error as shown in the following image:

[image]

The other error which is cut in above image is:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:390 
(find_package_handle_standard_args)
CMakeLists.txt:1257 (find_package)
```

Can anybody please tell what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you installed all the development versions of the prerequisite packages listed in the libwebsockets documentation and followed the instructions here: https://libwebsockets.org/lws-api-doc-master/html/md_READMEs_README_8build.html#cmw

Comment: yes I have installed openssl 32 bit as well as tried it for 64 bit system,the thing i could get is (NOTE: Preferably in the default location to make it easier for CMake to find them)

NOTE2: Be sure that OPENSSL_CONF environment variable is defined and points at <OpenSSL install="" location>="">.cfg                                                                                            my openssl path is C:\OpenSSL-Win32 which consist of bin and respective files